# Why checkbox is not checked?

Tags: angular

I use Angualar 2 Material.

```
<div *ngFor="let p of fltUsers; let i = index">
    <md-checkbox [checked]="p.checked" (click)="selectPersonal(p, i)"></md-checkbox>
</div>
```

When `p.checked` is true, it does not check this checkbox. Why?

Where `p.checked` is boolean type

Additional info:

```
 public selectPersonal(p: Personal, index: number) {
    this.fltUsers[index].checked = !this.fltUsers[index].checked;
    console.log(this.fltUsers[index]);
  }
```

The last that I tried:

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="p.checked" (change)="p.checked = !p.checked"></md-checkbox>
```

**Edit: Sorry, it works, just needed to start again NPM**

Comment: Because you're supposed to use ngModel. https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples

Comment: What does it mean? How to fix?

Comment: It means you should click on the link which points at examples of various checkboxes, all using ngModel.

Comment: I do this as in example.

Comment: No, you're not. You're using [checked], and th examples use ngModel.

Comment: I tried to use `<md-checkbox [checked]="p.checked" (click)="selectPersonal(p, i)"></md-checkbox>`, it does not work

Comment: Also I tried this with `<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="p.checked" (click)="selectPersonal(p, i)"></md-checkbox>`

Comment: Good. The second one should select the checkbox when p.checked is true. If it doesn't, then post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I posted all code in question

Comment: Then it can't work, because Angular components also need a TypeScript part. And they live inside an Angular application declared using a NgModule, which must be bootstrapped. 3 lines of HTML are very, very far from being a complete example. Here's a complete example: https://plnkr.co/edit/0quxW8itpqPIJ4He8Leg?p=preview

Comment: I use Typescript, it is connected to Angular

Comment: And yet there is 0 line of TypeScript in your question. So you didn't post "all code in question" as you claimed in your previous comment. Again, here's what a complete example looks like: https://plnkr.co/edit/0quxW8itpqPIJ4He8Leg?p=preview

Comment: I updated question

Comment: I see that action click does not change value check in model object